# VLC library error; cannot import it into code

Tags: python, macos, vlc

I'm attempting to run this code from GitHub: https://github.com/hemantapkh/PyBirthdayWish. I downloaded and imported VLC into python, but now I'm getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ashleen/Downloads/PyBirthdayWish-main/PyBirthdayWish.py", line 7, in 
import vlc
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vlc.py", line 210, in 
dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vlc.py", line 182, in find_lib
ctypes.CDLL(c)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ctypes/**init**.py", line 374, in **init**
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlccore.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/Applications/Python 3.10/IDLE.app/Contents/Frameworks/libvlccore.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlccore.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libvlccore.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Python 3.10/IDLE.app/Contents/Frameworks/libvlccore.9.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlccore.9.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libvlccore.9.dylib' (no such file)

I'm on Mac, and I'm using Python (3.10.0 and 64 bits) and I'm also using VLC (64 bits).

I don't have any coding experience/knowledge so I'm not exactly sure what to do, so any help would be appreciated!! Apologies in advance for any ignorant questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the requirements using `pip install -r requirements.txt`?
If you did, you may have possibly installed the wrong version of VLC, since it seems you have the wrong version of a certain library (see the last line of your error message).
When installing VLC (and other software) make sure you install the "apple silicon" version of it. This just means it will be able to run correctly on your computer.
[The apple silicon version of VLC is available here](https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.16/macosx/vlc-3.0.16-arm64.dmg)

Comment: You are absolutely correct!! The problem was the wrong version of VLC! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I do have another question, however! When I run the code, instead of the art, I only see lines of "[34mpress F11 and hit {Enter}...[0m
[34m
[0m
[34m
[0m[34m
[0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[34m [0m[31m[0m[31m_[0m[31m.[0m[31m.[0m[31m.[0m[31m_[0m[31m [0m[31m [0m[31m,[0m[31ms[0m[31m$[0m[31m$[0m[31m$[0m[31ms[0m[31m.[0m[31m" repeated over and over, but I'm not sure what this means?

Comment: All of those [0m[... are just formatting that got printed. The only text I see there is Press F11 and hit Enter. Maybe you need to press that to start the animation?

Comment: I did attempt to press F11/enter, but I'm still only being given the repeating numbers for some reason. The audio file is thankfully working (thank you again!!), but I'm not sure how to start the animation.

Comment: How are you running the script? You need to use a terminal that support color codes. The numbers you're seeing are formatting to tell the terminal which color to make the characters. If you're running through terminal, try `export CLICOLOR=1` before running the script to make sure you can display color.

Comment: I'm running the code through IDLE(?) using python; the terminal won't let me open the code and if I try copy and pasting it, only the latter half of the code gets pasted. I'm so sorry for not being able to provide more information; I'm a complete beginner and this is my first time looking at any code so I have no idea what I'm doing or looking at!

Comment: No problem! To run a script through the terminal directly, open a terminal where the script is located and run `python PyBirthdayWish.py` to run it with python. Good luck (and happy birthday)!